# Error in multiplication of two matrices in R language

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

I created two matrices m and n using the method `matrix()` and wanted to display their multiplication result. But when I tried using `A*B` and `A%*%B`, all I got was the errors:

> Error in m * n : non-numeric argument to binary operator

and

> Error in m %*% n : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments.

Here's the code where I checked if m and n are numerical matrices.

```
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1    3   
[2,] 2    4   
> n
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 5    7   
[2,] 6    8   
> is.matrix(m)
[1] TRUE
> is.matrix(n)
[1] TRUE
> str(m)
List of 4
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 2
 $ : num 3
 $ : num 4
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 2
> str(n)
List of 4
 $ : num 5
 $ : num 6
 $ : num 7
 $ : num 8
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 2
> m*n
Error in m * n : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> m%*%n
Error in m %*% n : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
>
```

I don't understand where's the problem. Any idea please?

Comment: You didn't provide a reproducible example, but the error is telling you that at least one of your matrices is not of type numeric.

Comment: @Imo I've already checked the type of my matrices: they are numeric!

Comment: You are working with weird data. `str` should not say that m is a list. The following: `m <- matrix(1:4, 2); str(m)` returns *int [1:2, 1:2] 1 2 3 4*. Yours says list. Iists are not numeric objects. To 'fix' this particular issue, you could do `m <- matrix(unlist(m), nrow(m))`. However, you should look into why your data is a list in the first place.

Comment: can you show us how you set up the "matrices" `m`and `n`.
Usually, if you set `m <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)` you would get ` > str(m)
 int [1:2, 1:2] 1 2 3 4`